# Create an array of LatLng pairs for a global grid

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, geojson, geo

Is there a way, a simple lib or something like this, where you can just say, createGlobalGrid(1000) and it would generate a list of points on a geospatial surface which would have max. 1000m distance from each other.

Or could some one help me with the calculation for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [SRTM data set](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/).  It's broken into segments with elevation posts at regular intervals depending upon the region.  Coverage over the United States is down to about 1 arcsecond (30 m) between elevation posts and non-US locales is at 3 arcseconds (90 m).